# Hadoop MultipleOutputs checksum

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am using MultipleOutputs to write several files in Reducer. However, when I am looking into the target folder I see that files are successfully written, but the checksum files are empty (though created). Is there any way to make MultipleOutputs to write checksums also?

I am adding named outputs in 'run' method

```
 MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "fld1",
    TextOutputFormat.class,
    Text.class, Text.class);
    ...
```

And writing to MultipleOutputs object in Reducer:

```
output = new MultipleOutputs(context);
...
output.write("fld1", key, new Text(Arrays.toString(myData)));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that MultipleOutputs object needs to be explicitly closed after writing is done. The following call solves the issue: output.close()